# Extract string after a symbol in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

How can I extract string after a symbol in Perl?

I tried doing some searches but even the code I found didn't work.

I'm trying to extract the string after a colon. So I want to show everything after the colon.

Example:

```
string = day1: string over here

substring = string over here
```

So far I have tried:

```
$substring = $string=~ /(\:.*)\s*$/;
```

But it only outputs the number 1 over and over.

Comment: The regex should be `/:\s*(.*)\s*$/`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because pattern matches in a scalar context are boolean tests. If you want to capture bracket content (capture groups), you need a list context. It's ok if the list is only one element though:

try this:

```
 my ( $substring ) = $string=~ /(\:.*)\s*$/;
```

Difference maybe a bit subtle, but basically - we are assigning 'all the hits' from the pattern match to a list... that comprises one element.

Note - that's so you can do:

```
my @matches = $string =~ m/(.)/g;
```

And get multiple 'hits' returned. If you do as above, you will only get the first match - which is irrelevant given your pattern, but you can do:

```
my ( $key, $value ) = $string =~ m/(\w+)=(\w+)/;
```

for example.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use parentheses to extract a part from text and then refer to the result stored in $1 variable.

look at example:

```
my $text = "day1: string over here";

print $1 if ($text =~ /:\s*(.+)$/);
```

but similar result may be recieved with this code too:

```
my $text = "day1: string over here"; 

my ($a) = $text =~ /:\s*(.+)$/;
print $a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve desire substring by using [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function also:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "day1: string over here";

my (undef, $substring) = split(':\s*', $string);

print $substring, "\n";
```

Output:

```
string over here
```

Or you can get this by using capturing group `()` in regex:

```
my $string = "day1: string over here";
$string =~ m/(.*)\:\s+(.*)$/;
my $substring = $2;
print $substring, "\n";
```

Comment: I am not clear why you capture two groups in the regex example, but then ignore one of them.

Comment: OP wanted to extract the string after colon, so I ignored first one.

Comment: Granted. But you could just omit the leading `(.*)` entirely, and just access `$1`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I wanted to show OP where is the first part and how capturing group works, so I didn't omit the leading part.